# O que este erro do git significa?

Tags: git, deploy, bitbucket, capistrano

Estou migrando um repositório git de servidor. Estou tirando do meu VPS e passando para o Bitbucket.

Peguei todos os branches do VPS e subi com sucesso para o serviço mencionado. Adicionei inclusive uma chave de implantação para que o servidor de staging consiga atualizar o código-fonte por lá. Nada de errado aconteceu e eu já consigo trabalhar tranquilamente. O problema acontece no momento da implantação.

O meu arquivo do capistrano está assim:

```
set :deploy_to, "/var/www/apps/#{fetch(:application)}"
set :branch, 'upgrade_infra'
set :rails_env, 'production'
```

Quando eu dou um

```
cap application deploy
```

Eu tenho este retorno no momento em que o Capistrano tenta fazer o pull ( ou seja lá o que ele faça pra recuperar o código-fonte ):

*SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as   root@qa.ultimatum.com.br: git exit status: 2

**git stdout: fatal: Not a valid object name**

tar: This does not look like a tar archive

tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

git stderr: Nothing written*

O que está me deixando louco é esse "not a valid object name". Está tudo ok no repositório. Todos os branches lá ( inclusive esse ). Todos perfeitamente sincronizados com o meu ambiente local.

O mais estranho, é que se eu mudo o nome do branch no capistrano pra *master*, funciona perfeitamente.

Pesquisei bastante e tudo indica que o problema é devido ao branch não existir no servidor remoto ou não ter nenhum commit, o que não é meu caso, visto que eu subi pra lá branches muito antigos, com milhares de commits.

Alguém por gentileza saberia me ajudar?

Comment: Tem certeza que possui um branch de nome `upgrade_infra`?

Comment: Sim @Math, certeza absoluta :/

Comment: Como aparece a linha desta branch `upgrade_infra` na saída do comando `git branch -a`?